# Как передать массив в функцию, чтобы его значения не изменились

Tags: c++, c, массивы, функции, указатели

Хотел реализовать сортировку вставкой и задался таким вопросом: как мне передать массив в функцию чтобы после обработки его значения не изменились в функции main?
Допустим я хочу передать массив в функцию, чтобы он там сортировался, вывести его в этой же функции, но чтобы при этом значения его не поменялись в функции main. 
Если когда я передаю обычную переменную в функцию, то она не изменится, а если массив то там передается указатель на массив и он полюбому изменит свои значения в функции main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

void PrintA(int A[], int N);
void Swap(int *a, int *b);
void InsertionSort(int A[], int N);

int main(void)
{
    const int N = 10;
    int A[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = 1 + rand() % 9;
    }

    printf("Array under insertion sort: \n");
    PrintA(A, N);

    InsertionSort(A, N);

    /*printf("Array after insertion sort: \n");
    PrintA(A, N);*/

    system("pause");
}

void PrintA(int A[], int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void Swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void InsertionSort(int A[], int N)
{
    int j;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && A[j - 1] > A[j])
        {
            Swap(&A[j - 1], &A[j]);
            j--;
        }
    }
    PrintA(A, N);
}
```

Пробовал как-то снять указатель на массив, но потом у меня были ошибки с функцией Swap в функции InsertionSort.

Comment: Никак. То что вы хотите в языках C/C++ не предусмотрено. Делайте копию своими ручками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только копирую массив во временную переменную а ля template

```
void InsertionSort(int A[], int N)
{
// Вот здесь:
    int template[A.Length];
    for(int i = 0;i < A.Length;i++)
        {
           template[i] = A[i];
        }  
    int j;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && template[j - 1] > template[j])
        {
            Swap(&template[j - 1], &template[j]);
            j--;
        }
    }
//Передаем наш массив
    PrintA(template, N);
}
```

Comment: Что это за язык?

Comment: Мне понравилось ваше решение, но только мне нужно чтобы массив не изменялся в функции main, а только в функции InsertionSort. Немного изменив ваш код я смог этого добиться.
Единственная проблема, то что я не могу создать новый массив в функции InsertionSort, вводя в квадратных скобках константу N, компилятор выдает ошибку, и с вашей функцией A.Lenght также.

Comment: Да,я исправил.Вот и проблема копипасты кода выявилась Xd @Maksud3

Comment: @TEA Я смог решить проблему с созданием прототипа массива в функции Insertion Point. Выделил память для массива через new, и ваш код заработал. Только я переименовал массив на другой, потому что template зарезервированное имя.

Comment: Тот же вопрос, что и у AnT. Что за `A.Length`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это типо чтобы узнать размер массива А, но оно не работало и я реализовал это таким образом:
`int *B = new int[N];`
И потом освободить память конечно.

Comment: .Length что то из области -std=c++1х. Там есть какие-то ново введения. Надежнее использовать конструкцию _sizeof(a1)/sizeof(a1[0])_ , это надежнее, можно оформить её в качестве макроса.

Comment: Для c++ разумно использовать их родные конструкторы, вот пример: std::array<int, 42> a1;
std::array<int, a1.size()> a2;

Comment: @NewView `.Length` нет ни в одном стандарте.

Comment: @NewView Размер `std::array` должен определяться во время компиляции, так что пришлось бы делать функцию шаблоном...

Comment: На с++ был бы совершенно иной код целиком, нежели тот который представлен выше, там чистый c99 :)

Answer (score 6):

может memcpy?

```
int main(void)
{
    const int N = 10;
    int A[N], B[N];

    ....код наполняющий массив A

    memcpy((void*)B, (void*)A, (sizeof(int) * N));
    PrintA(B, N);
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 2):

Просто массив нужно копировать - или самому, или встроенной функцией. Но есть один обходной путь - если массив встроен в структуру, то он копируется компилятором.

```
typedef struct Massiv_ {
    int A[100];
} Massiv;

void Sort(Massiv M, int N) {
    // Сортируем M.A - тот массив, что передан, тронут не будет
}
```

Comment: в таком случае будет отсортирован массив M.A, и он будет изменён, передаётся ссылка на объект, в данном примере M, так что все равно надо копировать руками A[] в M.A в любом случае.

Comment: Структура просто создаёт контейнер для массива, в данном случае. Такой подход удобно использовать если данных много и их надо объединить в одно целое для транспорта по методам и функциям.

Comment: @NewView О какой ссылке речь? Структура передается по значению, т.е. массив внутри нее копируется. [Пруф.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77cc6aeebcae0180)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, все верно, но я рассматривал конкретно этот код, он соответствует стандарту c99, хоть и указаны заголовки c++, речь же о нем в данном топике. Вот пример [работы](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/638b37733dc05f04)   оригинального кода. А вот [пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a4cdd6081ef4d45) того же кода с модификациями собранного как std=c99. Результаты идентичны, массив в структуре передаётся как ссылка.

Comment: @NewView У вас в коде структур нет. С тем, что массивы передаются в функцию по ссылке (если они снаружи струтктур), никто не спорит, но почему вы считаете, что внутри структуры он тоже передастся по ссылке? Кроме того, те результаты, что у вас по ссылкам, вы получите на любой версии стандарта.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, все верно :) кинул не тот код в пример, заработался :) ваши обоснование обсолютно верно, это так.